# How to get on the fly the following lists?

Tags: python

Hello I have the following dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'key1': ['color1','color2'],'key2':['car1','car2'],'key3':['frut1']}
```

from it I would like to get the following lists:

```
key1 = ['color1','color2']
key2 = ['car1','car2']
key3 = ['frut1']
```

I need to create this lists on the fly from the dictionary I tried:

```
list_keys = dictionary.keys()
list_values = dictionary.values()
```

and then:

```
keys, values = zip(*dictionary.items())
```

However I dont have the result that I need I think that maybe this task could be completed using exec, but I dont know how to proceed
    since that I would like to appreciate support to overcomet this task.

Comment: This is bad practice, because you could just use `dictionary['key1']` without any problems here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to get the list with the name of the key and the values that contains, I need a list peer key on memory with that names.

Comment: Really, you don't. You can work with the dictionary directly.

Comment: you mean you want to create variables `key1` etc dynamically from whatever keys you get in the dict? It still does make sense. Sounds like an XY problem. What you really need to do?

Comment: yes I need dinamically to extract the name of the key and then to generate a list with that name and with the corresponding values

Comment: To answer your question, you'll need `globals().update(dictionary)`. But please, don't actually do this.

Comment: You really don't want to do this. What's the real problem you're trying to solve? Can you give more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary is the only good way to store a variable number of variables. Your dictionary looks fine as it is.

If you want integer identifiers, e.g. the keys in your use case aren't actually numbered, below is an example of what you can do:

```
d = {'key1': ['color1', 'color2'],
     'key2': ['car1', 'car2'],
     'key3': ['frut1']}

values = {i: list(v) for i, (k, v) in enumerate(sorted(d.items()), 1)}

{1: ['color1', 'color2'],
 2: ['car1', 'car2'],
 3: ['frut1']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack after sorting the contents of the dictionary:

```
import re
dictionary = {'key1': ['color1','color2'],'key2':['car1','car2'],'key3':['frut1']}
key1, key2, key3 = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x:int(re.findall('\d+$', x[0])[0]))
```

Comment: I dont understand this solution since I have several values if I proceed like this I am going to write manually key1,key2,key3,...,keyN

Comment: @neo33 In that case, you will have to work with the dictionary you have by passing the keyname to the structure. As pointed out by coldspeed in the comments, there is no good way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why the downvote?